# eclipse subversion: revert

Tags: svn

I use eclipse Subversion. I did some local changes in the project and bevor commit I have updated the project. After updating, I noticed that I can not run the Project any more. Now I would like to go one step back, that means "remove the changes comming from the update". For this reason I go to Team -> Revert. My Question is, when I use "revert", only the changes comming from the UPDATE  will be undone or my changes, I created  before the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation:

> revert: Restore pristine working copy file (undo most local edits).
>   usage: revert PATH...

Your local changes will be undone.  The updated files will still be there.

Assume you were on revision X.  You then edited files, so you're at X with local modifications.  Then you updated.  So you're now on X + 1 with local modifications.  After reverting, you will be on X + 1 without local modifications.

Comment: @ Corbin thanks for the good explanation. How to undo the updated changes only?

Comment: @AhmedSalah To be honest, I'm not sure if there's an automated way to do that.  You could try "updating" to the previous revision, but I'm not sure if that will keep your changes, so make sure you back your files up first.  If that doesn't work, and the number of files is small, a simple solution would be to checkout the previous version and reapply your changes to it.  You probably shouldn't be working off of old files though.  That will cause problems (logical and technical) when you want to commit and your files are behind.